# Python: Print file names and their directory based on their file size

Tags: python

I want to print filenames and their directory if their filesize is more than a certain amount. I wrote one and set the bar 1KB, but it doesn't work even if there are plenty of files larger than 1KB.

```
import os, shutil

def deleteFiles(folder):
    folder = os.path.abspath(folder)

    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
         for filename in filenames:
            if os.path.getsize(filename) > 1000:
                print(filename + ' is inside: ' + foldername)

deleteFiles('C:\\Cyber\\Downloads')
```

And I got 'Nothing'!

and then I  wrote codes in interactive shell, I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#14>", line 3, in <module>
      if os.path.getsize(filename) > 100:
   File "C:\Users\Cyber\Downloads\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
 FileNotFoundError:
```

I am wondering How I can fix my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os` can't find the file without a given path, following your code, you have to re-specify the absolute path. Replace

```
if os.path.getsize(filename) > 1000:
```

with

```
if os.path.getsize(os.path.abspath(foldername + "/" + filename)) > 1000:
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you!! i didn't know i need to insert /

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
deleteFiles('C:\\Cyber\\Downloads')
```

with

```
import os

a = 'c:' # removed slash
b = 'Cyber' # removed slash
c = 'Downloads'

path = os.path.join(a + os.sep, b, c)
deleteFiles(path)
```

Comment: The book does not go too deep into OS-specific paths, so Windows paths are handled this way.

Comment: Welcome. This helps to let Python compute the right path and not trying to guess if forward slash or back slash should be used to properly construct it.